# My pageBlockTable headers are disappearing when I use the "rendered" attribute - how can I get them back?

Tags: visualforce, pageblocktable

I am losing the Headers on my pageBlockTable when I use the "rendered" attribute.  Is there a way for me to get these back?

Here is my table:

```
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!listOfBuyer}" var="by">
            <apex:column value="{!by.Name}" rendered="{! by.Funding_Status__c = 'Funds Needed'}"/> 
            <apex:column value="{!by.Spend_Last_Week__c}" rendered="{! by.Funding_Status__c = 'Funds Needed'}"/>
            <apex:column value="{!by.Total_Spend_this_Week__c}" rendered="{! by.Funding_Status__c = 'Funds Needed'}"/> 
            <apex:column value="{!by.Forecasted_Spend__c}" rendered="{! by.Funding_Status__c = 'Funds Needed'}"/>  
            <apex:column value="{!by.Current_Balance__c}" rendered="{! by.Funding_Status__c = 'Funds Needed'}"/> 
      </apex:pageBlockTable>
            </apex:pageBlock>
```

And here is my controller:

```
public class GUIDataController{

 public List<Buyer_Performance__c> listOfBP {get; set;}
 public List<Buyer__c> listOfBuyer {get; set;}
 public Buyer_Performance__c BP {get;set;}
 public Buyer__c Buyer {get;set;}

public GUIDataController() {
    listOfBP = [Select id, name, Call_Volume_This_Week__c, Spend_Last_Week__c, Week_to_Date_SpendFRM__c, Record_Scope__c from Buyer_Performance__c];
    listOfBuyer = [Select id, name, Approved_for_Invoices__c, Spend_Last_Week__c, Total_Spend_this_Week__c, Forecasted_Spend__c, Current_Balance__c, Funding_Status__c  from Buyer__c];
 }
 }
```

Would it be an option to do the filtering on my controller so that I don't have to render on the table?

Thanks,

John

Comment: Have you tried explicitly defining the column headers by using the headerValue attribute on the apex:columns ?

Comment: yes, to no avail!  I eneded up solving this by filtering the controller, so the table only returns matching values.  No need to render!!

Answer (score 1):

apex:columns represents the entire column of a table. When you specify a value for that column, it fetches a particular field of an object and binds it to that column, header being the field label.

What you need to understand for apex:pageBlockTable is that it does not allow you to have control over each row of data. So, if you need to specify rendered attribute for each row, its better to not opt for apex:pageBlockTable.

If control has to be set on page itself, I will suggest using a simple html table, with tr tag's style attribute having the display property set by your condition as:

```
style="{!IF( by.Funding_Status__c = 'Funds Needed', 'display:\'\'', 'display:none')}"
```

P.S. Havent tested it in any org, but if my memory serves me, this should work :)

Last but not the least, the condition can easily be provided in Where Clause of query and the list queried will not only return the desired records, the view state of the page will also be reduced.

```
listOfBuyer = [Select id, name, Approved_for_Invoices__c, Spend_Last_Week__c, Total_Spend_this_Week__c, Forecasted_Spend__c, Current_Balance__c, Funding_Status__c From Buyer__c Where Funding_Status__c = 'Funds Needed'];
```

Not sure of your particular use case but sure hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you add another statement in your render to check if there is an ID the headers should appear.

rendered="{!OR(by.Funding_Status__c = 'Funds Needed',id=''),true,false}"

This checks to see if there is an ID in the field (which there is not in a header field) and displays the data

Hope this helps?